# Isn't it redundant to use "then" after "if"?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage, redundancy

Since "if P, Q" is grammatical, is it not the case that the "then" in "if P, then Q" is redundant?

Where P and Q are clauses.

For example, "if it rains today, the road shall be wet tomorrow" is grammatically impeccable. (Or is it not?)

Doesn't that mean that the "then" in "if it rains today, then the road shall be wet tomorrow" is redundant?
I am referring to the logic that using a word would be redundant if the same meaning is conveyed without that word.

But I see that, when the antecedent clause gets too long, the occurrence of "then" serves to mark the distinction between the two clauses.

Except in that sense, can we not say that the usage "if ... then" is redundant in English, and should be replaced by "if ..." especially if the clauses are short enough?

Ah, except in programming languages, of course.

Comment: Can you give us an example to help clarify?

Comment: Actually, it *is* redundant ("syntactic sugar") in programming languages, but not in English.

Comment: @HotLicks But the two statements have got to be separated by something, right? Given that there are no commas in programming languages..(I know only about C, C++)

Comment: But there is no `then` keyword in C.  Pascal, Fortran, and, I think, Algol use `then` but could likely do without, at least in some cases.

Comment: @HotLicks Ohh sorry, you're right. I was talking about BASIC.

Comment: @HotLicks Actually it depends on the "syntax style" if you will. "Curly bracket" languages and most significant whitespace don't use them but others do (Visual Basic jumps to mind)

Comment: You can write an `if` statement in C without any curlies.

Comment: I've been working in DEC/Alpha Basic so long [since 1988  -  I said I was old-school] that I think I tend to overuse 'then' when speaking normal English.  But I agree that it's a good idea to use 'then' unless it's a simple sentence where the start of the consequence is obvious.

Comment: @DavidGarner I've been feeling for quite some time now that its somewhat jarring to use "then" when the two clauses are rather small, like three words or so. But as bcc32 has said below, it apparently has a different shade of meaning.

Comment: I'd not use a 'then' is such cases (but as you wisely point out, it might be useful with a long antecedent). But redundancy is largely a matter of style rather than of absolute correctness / incorrectness. And 'This room is spic' is incorrect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True. But what is "spic"??? I don't get that last statement.

Comment: The Phrase Finder has for _spick and span_ 'The alliteration in the phrase suggests the possibility that that one of the two words alluded to cleanliness and freshness and that the other just followed along.' (ie one's just there for prosodic effect, as with a 'goody-goody'. It's redundant: it contributes nothing to the meaning.) But spic/spick (or span) on its own is unacceptable. (... The use of spic ... is just an alternative spelling of spick.)

Comment: As a mathematician, I frequently write such conditional statements.  My advice: include the "then" unless perhaps the antecedent is *extremely* short.  Help the reader keep track.

Comment: Note that there is absolutely nothing wrong with having redundancy in ones writing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not consider it redundant to have if...then...

Leaving aside the point of using *then* to clearly mark where the consequent clause begins, the use of both *if* and *then* can serve to emphasize the causal nature of the antecedent, or to make it seem like an *if and only if* rather than just an *if*-*then*.

For example:

> If it rains, we will stay inside.

merely provides the plan of action in the case that it rains, whereas:

> If it rains, *then* we will stay inside.

seems to suggest that the staying inside will only happen if it rains (note the emphasis on *then*, which would be stressed in speech and italicized in writing).

Comment: bcc32's logic is fallacious. "If it rains, then we will stay inside" means that we will definitely stay inside if it rains, but rain is not a requirement for staying inside.

Comment: That’s what “If it rains, we’ll stay inside” means. If you add and stress _then_, the meaning does it fact come closer to meaning “We will only stay inside if it rains, otherwise we will [do whatever it we’re doing] outside” as bcc32 says. This is contingent upon actually stressing the _then_, though, which bcc32’s answer does not mention except for italicising the word.

Comment: The meaning is only changed if "then" is emphasized.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

"If X, then Y" is ordinary English usage and, although slightly redundant, is unobjectionable. 
Two related points: 
(a) "If and only if X" ("iff"), beloved of philosophers, seems to me redundant for "Only if X", as well as being awkward to speak or write - or am I missing something?
(b) Too often, I encounter "If then, ..." or "If, then, ... ." I know of no excuse for these. They seem to be awkward and confusing substitutions for "Then, if... ."

Comment: Nope. *Only if* is quite different from *if and only if* -- there is nothing redundant about the latter. P *only if* Q is typically translated in logic as Q implies P, not P is equivalent to Q (aka P if and only if Q, aka P implies Q and Q implies P). *P only if Q* is false only when Q is true and P is false. (This is the conventional interpretation for logic, but there are of course other interpretations. English is a natural language.)